# Can I use A2DP profile as audio input in a phone call for higher quality audio? I am aware this would remove the option for using microphone

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pi-4

I've been able to connect my raspberry pi 4 to my phone as a bluetooth HSP/HFP profile.  I used PulseAudio and ofono for that, following this tutorial: https://scribles.net/enabling-hands-free-profile-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-stretch-by-using-pulseaudio/

I used the onboard bluetooth without any external bluetooth dongle.

When I take calls with my raspberry pi 4, the audio quality is poor and 'robotic', as opposed to listening to music with A2DP profile where the audio quality is relatively clear.

After searching around, it seems to be the case that the poor audio quality seems to be related to the nature of HSP/HFP itself.

Is there a way to force an A2DP profile in a call for better audio quality? I am aware that forcing such a profile will remove the option to use microphone for audio output into the call, which I am okay with.

Is it possible to somehow 'trick' my phone into thinking that the bluetooth profile is HSP/HFP, but it's actually A2DP with microphone muted?

Thanks a lot guys, newbie here.